# Count SQL records based on sibling property

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of people who have a name, location (where they live), and a parent_id
(parents are stored on another table). So for example:

```
name    | location  | parent_id
--------+-----------+-----------
Joe     | Chicago   | 12
Sammy   | Chicago   | 13
Bob     | SF        | 13
Jim     | New York  | 13
Jane    | Chicago   | 14
Dave    | Portland  | 14
Al      | Chicago   | 15
Monica  | Boston    | 15
Debbie  | New York  | 15
Bill    | Chicago   | 16
Bruce   | New York  | 16
```

I need to count of how many people live in Chicago and have
siblings (share a parent_id) that live in New York. So for the example above,
the count would be 3.

```
name    | location  | parent_id
--------+-----------+-----------
Joe     | Chicago   | 12
Sammy   | Chicago   | 13   * sibling Jim lives in New York
Bob     | SF        | 13
Jim     | New York  | 13
Jane    | Chicago   | 14
Dave    | Portland  | 14
Al      | Chicago   | 15   * sibling Debbie lives in New York
Monica  | Boston    | 15
Debbie  | New York  | 15
Bill    | Chicago   | 16   * sibling Bruce lives in New York
Bruce   | New York  | 16
```

Can someone help me write the SQL to query this count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correlated query is a very nice way to go and is very efficient.  Avoid the use of distinct as it is an expensive operation.  Group by is a nice alternative over the use of distinct.  Understand the data and structure the query accordingly.  Here is another option that is engine optimized...

```
select count(*) 
from (select * from #t where Location = 'Chicago') ch
inner join (select * from #t where Location = 'New York') ny on ch.ParentID = ny.ParentID
```

Comment: Those are not a correlated subqueries, they are just subqueries, and your answer suffers from the same problem PD1ce's initially did; it is going to count people in Chicago with N siblings in New York N times.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like Minh's answer works great, but here is another example using a Self Join.

```
SELECT Count(DISTINCT a.child_id)
FROM people a
    JOIN people b ON a.parent_id = b.parent_id
WHERE a.location = 'Chicago' AND b.location = 'New York'
```

Should produce "3" for just the above table listed.

EDIT: Added a DISTINCT a.parent_id based on Lithis' suggestion.

EDIT2: As noted by Uueerdo, a child_id or some sort of unique id would really help in the case of 2 siblings who live in Chicago and 1 sibling who lives in New York. I have edited the original query to reflect this.

Since this is not truly an "answer" to your question, because there is no such child_id, I would defer to Uueerdo's answer, sorry!

Comment: I haven't run the query, but it seems like it would count a single person twice if they have two different siblings in New York. Perhaps adding `GROUP BY a.id` or using `COUNT(DISTINCT a.id)` would prevent this.

Comment: You are correct Lithis, did not catch that.  I'll edit my post.

Comment: You really need a "child id", if two people in Chicago have the same parent, they'll only be counted once now. Actually, would `COUNT(DISTINCT a.*)` maybe work?

Comment: Yeah a child_id would be ideal, and hopefully that is included in OP's table, but I was just going off of the table presented.

Comment: Yes, there is `child_id`. I'll let you know how the query turns out.

Comment: I should also say, I'm running this on a ridiculously large table, but it only needs to run once a day (if that) so performance is important, but not crucial.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM `people` AS p1
WHERE p1.`location` = 'Chicago'
      AND p1.parent_id IN (
         SELECT DISTINCT parent_id 
         FROM `people` AS p2
         WHERE p2.`location` = 'New York'
        )
;
```

Using Minh's as a base, this should be pretty fast; since the subquery is no longer "correlated", it should not risk the possibility of it needing executed repeatedly, once for every row in `people`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try this?

```
SELECT Count(*)
FROM table table1
WHERE table1.location= 'Chicago'
      AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table table2
                     WHERE table1.parent_id= table2.parent_id
                           AND table2.location= 'New York')
```